# signal prior QThread event loop start is lost

Tags: c++, qt

I have a case where a signal is being lost and I don't understand why -- normally signals sent prior to the event loop starting just get queued up and sent then.

This is what the code looks like (for a QThread object):

```
void OffloadHandler::run()
{
    cout << "Start" << endl;
    connect( this, SIGNAL(loopStarted()), SLOT(onLoopStarted()), Qt::QueuedConnection );
    emit loopStarted();
    exec();
}

void OffloadHandler::onLoopStarted()
{
    cout << "Here!" << endl;
}
```

The thread is started elsewhere and `Start` is written to the console but `Here1` never is -- the signal is not received. I use the same pattern in my main message loop and it works, but in this threaded message loop it appears not to work.

Is there anything clearly wrong in my code here?

Comment: Where is this "loopStarted" emitted?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid and it should run. Are you sure you have an event loop running in the thread that `oh` is created in?

Cause the `emit loopStarted()` should send an event to `oh`'s event loop, which will be processed and will call `onLoopStarted()`. I've tested your code out, and it works for me.

---

Btw, It's generally recommended that you do not add slots to your `QThread`, and avoid using `moveToThread( this );`

Unfortunately, I don't really understand your use case, so I can't give a better solution. But [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects) is some amazing documentation which has nice DOs and DONTs regarding `QThread`s.

Comment: +0.5 :) That's an interesting article but I wish it didn't give examples of suclassing `QThread`. I believe the suggestions there that center on putting work in a `QObject` subclass and moving that to a `QThread` instance is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out, I've been bitten by the QThread ownership oddity. One has to be really careful when connecting to the QThread object itself since that Object is not owned by the thread by default.

So at the point where the thread is created I must move the thread to the thread:

```
OffloadHandler * oh = new OffloadHandler();
oh->moveToThread( oh ); //MOVE TO SELF!
oh->start();
```

Once I do this the signals work as expected.

Comment: Although the Qt documentation recommends subclassing QThread, it is generally considered contrary to the intended use. Moving a thread to itself is definitely a common anti-pattern that continues to propagate :) It may solve your immediate problem but the problems it produces are more insidious. Do a search on SO for Qt and threads and you should find many mentions of this article: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: While perhaps a nice idea not to subclass I don't see ho you'd be able to start the message loop in the thread then. `exec` is a protected member function -- and it seems rather silly to create a new QEventLoop for this purpose.

Comment: I also don't buy the bit about not moving a thread to itself. The thread has no owner thread, what is so special about the thread which happened to create it -- it's now it's own independent entity.

Comment: `exec()` is called automatically from run, you don't have to subclass for this to happen.

Comment: Well, then I guess there's no way to create a thread without a message loop without subclassing.