# Threading in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I read on internet that subclassing (that deriving a class from Qthread) and then over writing run function to perform the required task is not the correct way to use Qthread. But i have read in some books and on Qt documentation to use the subclassing way?

can you tell me why shouldn't use the subclassing way? Subclassing Qthread is an easy way to use thread (for me because i am a beginner).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt Programming and computations which take long time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300983/qt-programming-and-computations-which-take-long-time)

Comment: @Nawaz, this may come from the recent answer to one of my questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638226/signal-prior-qthread-event-loop-start-is-lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QThread was designed and is intended to be used as an interface or a control point to an operating system thread, not as a place to put code that you want to run in a thread. We object-oriented programmers subclass because we want to extend or specialize the base class functionality. The only valid reasons I can think of for subclassing QThread is to add functionality that QThread doesn’t have, e.g. perhaps providing a pointer to memory to use as the thread’s stack, or possibly adding real-time interfaces/support. Code to download a file, or to query a database, or to do any other kind of processing should not be added to a subclass of QThread; it should be encapsulated in an object of it’s own.

for more details please check this..

http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @ shobi
Sir what does creating thread means? and What does this statement means? Never mind:)
"all of the functions in QThread were written and intended to be called from the creating thread, not the thread that QThread starts"

Comment: @UmerFarooq if u want to create a thread then u can do it by just creating the object of QThread class, u dont need to have a class that is subclassing the QThread class.

Comment: yeah thanks sir there is a bit confusion left.
as Koying mentioned:" it manages the thread in which resides a different event loop". What does this means

Comment: it means that ur QThread is like a wrapper which handles threading. Now when u instantiate an object of QThread at that time the new thread is created, this means that the method in which QThread's object is created is on main thread and the method in which u call the QThread::start() is on the newly created thread.

Comment: Qt is very old, this article is quite new. The interface of QThread clearly intends on deriving. Some functionality, like not having a message loop, can *only* be achieved by deriving from QThread.

Answer (score 2):

See this great article about QThread: [The great QThread Mess by Christoph Eckert](http://www.christeck.de/wp/2010/10/23/the-great-qthread-mess/), which lead me to use QThread's this way, now: [Threading without the headache by Bradley T. Hughes](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/)

Bottom line: IMHO, the easiest way to use QThread is to create an QObject subclass, use signals/slots and use `moveToThread` to have the object live in a different thread with a different event loop. 
Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you absolutely need a `"while(true)"` kind of thread, but it is very often avoidable in Qt.

Comment: will you please mind to tell what does this means! it is preety confusing for a beginner.
"all of the functions in QThread were written and intended to be called from the CREATING THREAD, not the thread that QThread starts"

Comment: The creating thread is the thread that "owns" the QThread object. QThread itself is not the thread, it manages the thread in which resides a different event loop, which explains "the thread that QThread starts"

Answer (score 1):

The [QThread documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QThread.html) explicitly states that subclassing is the right thing to do:

> To create your own threads, subclass `QThread` and reimplement `run()`.

This is somewhat puzzling though, because (as shobi points out in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645731/14637)) it is an ugly design and there is an alternative solution.

Comment: shobi's answer neglects to mention the API is currently not fully suitable for the other solution. Unlike a nice API like boost thread, you can't just easily provide any function to act in the thread -- the signal/slot approach is far more complicated and assumes you want an event loop, which may not be true.